# max size in BlobProperty (appengine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

What is the maximum size of one BlobProperty in appengine? 
I'm not talking about of the Blobstore API, i'm referring to the property class [BlobProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#BlobProperty)

Please add a link who support your answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The limit is 1 megabyte. [Docs here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entitiesandmodels.html#Properties_and_Types).

> Like db.Text, a db.Blob value can be
>   as large as 1 megabyte, but is not
>   indexed, and cannot be used in query
>   filters or sort orders. The db.Blob
>   class takes a str value as an argument
>   to its constructor. Blobs are modeled
>   using the BlobProperty class.

Comment: In practice, it's smaller than 1 MB, since the entire call to the datastore API is limited to 1MB; the actual biggest size is 1MB - the size of any other properties in the model (which may very well be 0) - serialization overhead (which is fairly small, but you still don't want to try stuffing exactly 1024*1024 bytes in a blob).

Comment: as per ndb docs "if indexed is False (the default), unlimited length, not indexed." so, does it mean it no longer is limited to 1Mb?

Comment: But don't forget BlobProperty can use the compressed keyword. Depending on your data, you can fit quite a lot more than 1MB.